# Save items starting with 'S' from list l to l2 using Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need to save all the list items starting with 'S' from list l to l2

```
l= ['Santa Cruz','Santa fe','Sumbai','Delhi']
l1 = []
l1 = list(map(lambda x : x if x[0] == 'S',l))
print(l1)
```

Above has resulted in an syntax error.

I tried
**Trial-I**

```
l= ['Santa Cruz','Santa fe','Sumbai','Delhi']
l1 = []
l1 = list(map(lambda x : x if x[0] == 'S' else '',l))
l1
```

and it returns [True, True, True, False]

my expected output is ['Santa Cruz','Santa fe','Sumbai']

**Trial-II**

```
l= ['Santa Cruz','Santa fe','Sumbai','Delhi']
l1 = []
l1 = list(map(lambda x : x[0] == 'S',l))
print(l1)
```

**Trial-II** returned ['Santa Cruz','Santa fe','Sumbai', '']

my expected result should not have the blank list item in the ending.

Answer (score 4):

```
l= ['Santa Cruz','Santa fe','Sumbai','Delhi']
l1 = [name for name in l if name.startswith("S")]
```

---

## Edit

All strings have a method called `startswith`. Taking the 0th element of the string would also have done the trick.

For list comprehensions, what is going on in the line `l1 = [name for name in l if name.startswith("S")]` is basically the same as

```
l= ['Santa Cruz','Santa fe','Sumbai','Delhi']
l1 = []

for name in l:
    if name.startswith("S"): # also: if name[0] == "S" would work
        l1.append(name)
```

But a more consise way of writing it down

Comment: This answer is good but you should provide a little bit of explanation of how list comprehensions work as well as noting that all strings have a ```startswith``` method.

Comment: thsi is good, but I am looking for suggestions using lambda not regular functions.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
 [x for x in l if x[0] == 'S']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use if without else inside lambda. If you want to use lambda necessarily, you can use filter instead of map:

```
l1=list(filter(lambda x: x[0] == 'S', l))

>>> print(l1)

['Santa Cruz', 'Santa fe', 'Sumbai']
```

If you want to count the words starting with 'S' using Map function, as per your comment, you can do the following:

```
result=sum(list(map(lambda x : 1 if x[0] == 'S' else 0,l)))

>>> print(result)

3
```

Comment: I know we can use filter, but I want to use Map. Using the function Map, count the number of words that start with ‘S’ in input_list.

Comment: Added another version using map, please check

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension:
this means, append each element `x` in `l` to `l1` if the 0th element in `x` is the string `"S"`.

```py
l1 = [x for x in l if x[0] == 'S']
```